# SAPUI5: DOM change commands interfere with each other

Tags: javascript, sapui5

My List Binding:

```
<StandardListItem 
  title="{NewProposalTitle_DE}" 
  description="Stream: {Stream}, Time: {starttime}" 
  press="handlePress" 
>
```

I want to change the `title`'s binding to `title="{NewProposalTitle_EN}"` from the oData model, when the user is english.

I looked into expression binding but this doesn't seem to work with dynamic data:

```
title="{= {language} === "de" ? {NewProposalTitle_DE} : {NewProposalTitle_EN} }
```

So I tried a different approach where I iterate through all items from a SAPUI5 List and want to change the (german) `title` attribute to the english one if the language of the user is english and add a number to the Item's `counter` attribute.

```
var Items = this.getView().byId("idList").getItems();
for (var i = 0; i < Items.length; ++i) {
  if(language === "en"){
    Items[i].setTitle(oData.results[i].Title_EN);
  }
  Items[i].setCounter(numbers[i]);
}
```

If the language is german, everything works like a charm and the counter is set correctly, but if the language is english, things get fishy. 
When the Title gets updated with the english title, the counter is set back to 0 (default). Even more strange, if the german and the english version of the title are equal (so no change needs to be done) the counter is still shown (i assume SAPUI5 is smart enough to recognize, that no change needs to be done).

I encountered the same problem, when I tried to add a Style Class for the Item:

```
Items[i].addStyleClass("blue");
```

again, as long as the `title` doesn't get changed it works.

I tried changing the order in every possible way without success.
I also tried to `setCounter` and `addStyleClass` and omitted the `setTitle` command but only one affected the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers! I figured out a solution for my problem:

In the controller, I check for the users language and update the property binding:

```
Items[i].bindProperty("title", "NewProposalTitle_EN");
```

It may not be the most elegant or correct way, but it works for me (at the moment).

I hope you all have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

**Please don't translate this way! You might end up overwriting data in your other models**. Use the i18n resource models to do your translations! It's the go-to, built in way to translate any text in your application to any other language.

SAPUI5 loads the right ones by default.

[image]

If your browser's language is set to German, it will try to load `i18n_de_DE.properties` first, (not sure of the exact name for German, you'll find out if you look at the network tab of the browser. Could be just `_de.properties` if there's such a thing as `_de_AT` or something) before falling back to the default `i18n.properties`.

If you start an application from any of the usual IDE's like webIDE or eclipse, the model is already created for you.

The idea is to set the title to an identifier, like

```
<Label text={i18n>MY_TRANSLATABLE_TEXT} />
```

In your i18n.properties file, you might default to English:

```
MY_TRANSLATABLE_TEXT=Customer
```

While your German properties file has

```
MY_TRANSLATABLE_TEXT=Kunde
```

The translation is then done for you without trying to mess with the titles directly.

Comment: I am aware of i18n and use it for static text. I don't think i18n helps me here, as I get the title from a OData service. I tried to change the binding for the title attribute: from `text={NewProposalTitle_DE}` to `title={NewProposalTitle_EN}` but the binding didn't work and all I got was the title being a static String "{NewProposalTitle_EN}". Then I tried the differen approach descriped above, iterating through the Items and manually changing the title. (See edits above)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> title="{= {language} === "de" ? {NewProposalTitle_DE} : {NewProposalTitle_EN} }
> ```

There are some syntactical issues in your [expression binding](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0). Try with this:

```
title="{= ${language} === 'de' ? ${NewProposalTitle_DE} : ${NewProposalTitle_EN} }"
```

---

Besides that, I don't think it's a good idea to put translatable texts into the entity set as properties. I'd recommend to define field label (e.g. for the `NewProposal` property) translated in each language as a [UI text annotation](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_gateway20sp12/2.0/en-US/30/6e8c537c8fcc26e10000000a4450e5/frameset.htm) 
 (such as `sap:label`).

When an ODataModel is created, the service metadata will be requested immediately with the corresponding language query `sap-language =`[`<automatically detected>`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1354#issue-210098990).

[image]

Thus the property labels come already translated from the backend system, contained in the metadata, which you can bind in the view via special property binding syntax. E.g.:

#### In Metadata

```
<EntityType Name="BusinessPartner" sap:content-version="1">
  <Key>
    <PropertyRef Name="BusinessPartnerID" />
  </Key>
  <Property Name="BusinessPartnerID" Type="Edm.String"
    sap:label="Business Partner ID"
    sap:creatable="false"
    sap:updatable="false"
  />
  ...
</EntityType>
```

#### [Property Metadata Binding](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/f5aa4bb75c20445194494b264d3b3cd2)

```
<StandardListItem 
  title="{myModelName>BusinessPartnerID/#@sap:label}" 
  press=".handlePress" 
/>
```

Comment: thank you for the corrected expression binding!

I fear I do not completely understand the Property Metadata Binding but thanks anyway for the alternative solution!

Comment: @joelplambeck I extended my answer and included some links that explain how property metadata binding could be leveraged.

Comment: thank you for the links, seems very interesting and powerful. Looks like the propper way to handle a situation like mine...

But how do I configure a property as `sap:label`?

Comment: @joelplambeck The GW developer should be able to configure texts (short, medium, long, header, and description) in each field as [explained here](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_gateway20sp12/2.0/en-US/30/6e8c537c8fcc26e10000000a4450e5/frameset.htm) which will then produce `sap:label` in each property of `<EntityType>` inside metadata. Unfortunately, I don't have any expertise in backend. So I can't tell how exactly it is done in GW. Let me know if you could solve it!